# Php Dynamic Variable

Tags: php, dynamic-variables

```
$X['high'] = 1234;
$var = array("X","high");
```

This is working:

```
$temp = $$var[0];
$temp = $temp[$var[1]];
echo $temp;
```

But this isn't working:

```
echo $$var[0][$var[1]];
```

Why? How can i make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explain to php parser how you want this statement to be parsed:

```
echo ${$var[0]}[$var[1]];
```

Without brackets you will have:

php7

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /in/cvZqc on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Array in /in/cvZqc on line 5

php5

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'high' in /in/cvZqc on line 5
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in /in/cvZqc on line 5

[Sample link](https://3v4l.org/cvZqc).

Comment: Make it perfect and show , before and after PHP7 syntax, or just notice that :)